# How can I turn off CakePHP 3 validation only when a field is dirty?

Tags: php, validation, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm working with saving edits to an entity - the only trouble is that this password validation function below is part of the UsersTable, and it wants to be called even when I'm not making a change to the password field:

```
->add('password',[
    'custom'=>[
        'rule'=> function($value, $context){
            $pattern = '$\S*(?=\S{8,})(?=\S*[a-z])(?=\S*[A-Z])(?=\S*[\d])(?=\S*[\W])\S*$';
                return (bool)preg_match($pattern, $context['providers']['entity']->beforeHash);
            },
        'message'=>'Your password must have 1 uppercase letter, 1 lowercase letter, 1 number, and 1 special character ie. !@#$%'
    ],
])
```

I tried adding a statement to it - the 'on' parameter as described in the documentation:

```
'on' => function ($context) {
    return empty($context['providers']['password]);
 },
```

This allowed me to make the changes, as it only runs the validation when the field is empty (i.e., when we first create a user).

Unfortunately, it also broke my other functions - change and reset password. In those cases, a password is set in the field, so the validation won't apply when I'm trying to change or reset my password.

So I talked to the Github CakePHP3 guys on it and they suggested I check the dirty field to see whether or not a password was trying to be changed.

It's a great idea, but how do I access the field? Once I get deep into the array, I can't go any further:

```
$context['providers']['entity'] // this returns my object, but doesn't go deep enough
$context['providers']['entity']['dirty'] // this doesn't work - returns null, even though there is data inside on the debug
```

So how can I access the dirty array from the context I'm in? If I can see that the password field is being updated, I can make an exception and fix the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it! For future reference, this is how you do it:

dirty() checks to see whether or not a field has been modified.

```
       ->validatePresence('password', 'create')
        ->add('password',[
            'custom'=>[
                'rule'=> function($value, $context){
                    $pattern = '$\S*(?=\S{8,})(?=\S*[a-z])(?=\S*[A-Z])(?=\S*[\d])(?=\S*[\W])\S*$';
                    return (bool)preg_match($pattern, $context['providers']['entity']->beforeHash);
                },
                'on' => function ($context) {
                    return $context['providers']['entity']->dirty('password');
                },
                'message'=>'Your password must have 1 uppercase letter, 1 lowercase letter, 1 number, and 1 special character ie. !@#$%'
            ],
        ])
```